# Bot Framework + Facebook Tester = No messages

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger-bot, azure-bot-service

We have an assistant built using the bot framework (V3 SDK).  It is connected to the Facebook channel.

Within the Facebook page setup, we have a group of testers configured.

One of our testers does not receive a response from the bot.  Other testers do. We have removed the user from the test group, and have readded him (same as our other testers who are working fine), and still no responses.

The messages from the user show in the page's inbox.

Our logging shows that it never gets to the bot framework though.

Note, we have 10+ testers, and this is the only user that has this issue. All others, are able to send and receive messages as expected.

When I connect using ngrok, the messages are routed properly, and the conversation occurs as expected. I then disconnect ngrok, and the user is no longer able to have a conversation again.

The user was able to test for the previous 8 months, and this issue just started about two weeks ago.

I am at a loss for what it could be.

Comment: Going out on a limb because this is a heck of a conundrum, but the user has confirmed the request to be a tester, right? I'm assuming so because at 10+ testers, this is not your first go-round.

Comment: The user is configured as a tester yes.  Same configuration as all the others.  What's even more perplexing, is that this morning, all is functioning properly. NOTHING was changed lol.

Comment: There is literally no reason why one tester, opening a dialog with the same bot as all the other testers, should not be able to communicate with the bot. It almost feels like their Facebook admin settings have changed. Is this tester, or any of your testers, registered as developers on Facebook? Have any of those settings changed?

Comment: Nope, we even removed him, and readded him as if to "trigger" an update of some sort. I'm hoping this turns out to be a caching/network/IT at work related thing that just goes away at this point.